# Best way to dynamically set host server in ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I use the following to dynamically detect the host server. The importance for making it dynamic is that currently there are too many hard coded redirect such as:

```
http:s//mysite.com/hr/index.cfm
```

within my app. 
When I'm moving from production site to development site and then back to production site, I have to manually change/comment out this http/https one by one and it is not only time consuming but also dangerous.

Here is the code I found that can detect the host server. Then I do the following:

```
      <CFSET inet = CreateObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress")>
      <CFSET inet = inet.getLocalHost()>
      <CFSET HostServer = "#inet.getHostName()#">
      <CFSET ThisHostServer = "#LEFT(HostServer,6)#">
      <CFSWITCH expression="#Trim(ThisHostServer)#"><!--- Prod or Dev server --->
         <CFCASE value="myprodsite.com">
           <CFSET UseThisURL = "http://myprodsite.com">
         </CFCASE>
         <CFCASE value="mydevsite.com">
           <CFSET UseThisURL = "http://myDevsite.com">
         </CFCASE>
      </CFSWITCH>
```

Then on each page where links or redirection exist, I just need to use:

```
      #UseThisURL#/hr/index.cfm
```

My question is:

1. Where is the best way to set `#UseThisURL#` in the application?
   I'm using ColdFusion 10 and Application.cfc in Linux env.
2. Should I set it as an application or a session scope?
3. Since everything will be in an application or session scope, when users are idle on a certain page and the application/session scope is expired, when user click on a link will it generate an error? How to prevent users from seeing error caused by using this technique? Please advice, thank you!

Comment: cgi.server_name should have the domain if that is helpful, but a better question might be why are you using it at all?  If you are just doing redirects, why not use relative URLs or absolute URLs from the webroot? So redirect to /my/new/path instead of http://example.com/my/new/path.  That way it is domain agnostic and more portable.

Comment: The problem can be solved with no extra code, nor any extra configuration by simply doing what @SeanCoyne noted. Quick, easy, will always work regardless of the server on which the code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice that I used is creating `config.cfc` which can contain function like `getServerSpecificVariables()` to return structure. this structure will be saved in your application scope since you don't want to create `USEThisURL` for every session start. When you need to reset simply clear your application scope. instantiate below `config` component inside `onApplicationStart` event in `Application.cfc`
Example

Config.cfc:

```
component{

    public struct function getServerSpeceficVariables(){
       var config = {};
       var inet = CreateObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress");
       inet = inet.getLocalHost();
       HostServer = inet.getHostName();
       ThisHostServer = LEFT(HostServer,6);
       switch(Trim(ThisHostServer)){
           case 'myprodsite.com':{
              config.useThisURL = '';
              break;
           }

          case 'mydevsite.com':{
              config.useThisURL = '';
              break;
           }

         }
         return config;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Andi, I created config.cfc but I'm not sure how can I instantiate and clear application scope from onApplicationStart. I'm new to CF and so far has not yet used Application.cfc. I know how to instantiate an object by doing the following but not in onApplicationStart. I usually do this:  <CFSET ValReqFieldObj = New cfcomponents.ReqFields('#Trim(session.userid)#')> and then <CFSET ThisUser = ValReqFieldObj.checkReqFields()>

Comment: That was a mistake: here is the right codes: <CFSET ValDupParent1Obj = createObject("component", "cfcomponents.ParentComp.Dup_and_Relationship").init('#Trim(form.userid)#')> then <CFINVOKE component="#ValDupParent1Obj#" method="GetDups" returnvariable="DupExist">

Comment: Is this how to instantiate in OnApplicationStart?   OnApplicationStart I wrote:
  <!--- Instantiate a Config Obj  --->
  <CFSET ConfigObj = createObject("component", "cfcomponents.config").init()>
         <CFINVOKE component="#ConfigObj#" method="getServerSpeceficVariables" returnvariable="ServerName">
  <CFIF Len(Trim(ServerName)) NEQ 0>
    <cfset application.ThisServerName="#Trim(ServerName)#">
  <CFELSE>
     <!--- error message --->
                   <cfabort>
  </CFIF>

Comment: inside onApplicationStart <cfset application.config = new Config().getServerSpeceficVariables() />
to reference your variable everywhere in your project use ex..
<a href="#application.config.yourSiteURL#/index.cfm>Home</a>

Comment: I got an error:  The method getServerSpeceficVariables was not found in component /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/cfcomponents/GL/Config.cfc I checked multiple times that the path to .cfc and the name of .cfc (with capital C) is correct. I placed my Config.cfc in a GL subfolder under cfcomponents folder and in OnApplicationStart I referenced it as:<cfset application.config = New cfcomponents.GL.Config().getServerSpeceficVariables() />.

Comment: The whole folder system is under https (webdocsec). It's in Linux, does it matter?

Comment: This also gives the same error: I eliminated the first () <cfset application.config = New cfcomponents.GL.Config.getServerSpeceficVariables() />